# show holomorphic function is 0

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I'm trying to show that a holomorphic function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying
$$|f(z)|\leq\sqrt{|z|}$$
for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is $0$. Is it possible to use Poisson's formula here? Otherwise, how can I go about it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: Consider $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z}$ and use Liouville's Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write $\Gamma_{r,z}$ for the circle of radius $r$ around $z$, then by Cauchy's formula
\begin{align}
|f(z)|&=\frac1{2\pi}\,\left|\int_{\Gamma_{r,z}}\frac{f(\gamma)}{\gamma-z}\,d\gamma\right|
\leq\frac1{2\pi}\,\int_{\Gamma_{r,z}}\frac{|f(\gamma)|}{r}\,d\gamma
\leq\frac1{2\pi r}\int_{\Gamma_{r,z}}\sqrt{|\gamma|}\,d\gamma\\ \ \\
&\leq\frac{2\pi\sqrt{|z|+ r}}{2\pi r}
=\frac{\sqrt{1+|z|/r}}{\sqrt r}\xrightarrow[r\to\infty]{}0.
\end{align}